# У меня есть здесь ошибка CS0051 ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Я создал interface и внем 2 клас, и когда я делаю компилацию придет ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ПОМОГИТЕ!!!

Comment: А вообще тут не принято приводить код скриншотами. Весь имеющий отношение к вопросу код должен быть в виде текста.

Comment: выложите пожалуйста код, изображение имеет малую информативность

Comment: Текст ошибки и код текстом вставьте пожалуйста, чтобы не пришлось перепечатыват ьс картинки, если потребуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, у вас интерфейс `IMessageSender` имеет модификатор доступности строже, чем `public`, поэтому он никак не может быть передан в `public` функцию `Configure`. По крайней мере ошибка говорит об этом.

Вообще это странно, что у вас так сделано, интерфейсы по умолчанию имеют доступ `public`, это ведь **публичный контракт** по сути, так какой смысл в интерфейсе, если к нему не будет доступа из внешних сущностей?

В общем, уберите в описании интерфейса `IMessageSender` модификатор доступности, если вы какой-то ему написали (`private` или `protected`), ну или явно сделайте его `public`.

Comment: меня дали задание и я решаю задание

Comment: но не понимаю как

Comment: Покажите код интерфейса, если до сих пор непонятно в чём дело, хотя мне кажется я всё объяснил.